# Is there a way that i can connect inputs together?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 3 `input` fields that I would like to connect/link to each other. I want them to have a total value limited to 100%. So if 1 input is 40% then the other 2 `input` have 60% left to distribute in their value.

I am trying to find my answer on google, but i think I am searching with the wrong criteria. Does somebody know how to do this or have a guide on how to do it?

```html
<div class="form_groep">
  <label class="input_label_koolhydraten"><b>Koolhydraten</b></label>
  <input class="input_macro_koolhydraten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_koolhyrdaten" required><span>%</span>
</div>
<div class="form_groep">
  <label class="input_label_eiwitten"><b>Eiwitten</b></label>
  <input class="input_macro_eiwitten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_eiwitten" required><span>%</span>
</div>
<div class="form_groep">
  <label class="input_label_vetten"><b>Vetten</b></label>
  <input class="input_macro_vetten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_vetten" required><span>%</span><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you wanna do this on the client side or server side? And what kinda backend is this? Java Servlets or Java Server Pages?

Comment: Wheres your Java code?

Comment: I want to do it with javascript, i think that is client side, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @JasonHayes123 Yep. You got confused between Java and JavaScript./

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I am using JSP right now.

Comment: The first thing you can do is to check for the values and calculate the allowances on `blur` event or `keyup` event.

Comment: @Tom I haven't made a code yet, i am clueless on what i have to do right now.

Comment: Okay, so definitely you need Java then.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I am getting confused and i am probably confusing you to. I am making a calculator using HTML, CSS and Javascript. I am making it with a program called brackets and i'm using the browser to see the results.

Comment: Yea, that was confusing when you said you are working on Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have 3 inputs that the sum of its values do not exceeds 100, right?
If yes, so my code below can help you. There you will get all inputs in an array, then add a listener to the change of each one. This Listener will get the value of the `input` that is being changed and check if its value summed with the value of ther others don't exceed 100.

Check the code and if you didn't understand something, tell in the comments.
Also, warn me if I understood you wrong.

```js
let total = 0;
const ipts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));
const totalElem = document.getElementById("total")

for (var i = 0; i < ipts.length; i++){
  ipts[i].onchange = countTotal
}

function countTotal(){
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  total = ipts.reduce((counter,elem) => parseFloat(elem.value) + counter, 0);
  total -= value;
  if (value > 100){
    this.value = 100;
  }
  if (value + total > 100){
    this.value = 100 - total;
  }  
  totalElem.innerText = total + parseFloat(this.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="form_groep">
  <label class="input_label_koolhydraten"><b>Koolhydraten</b></label>
  <input class="input_macro_koolhydraten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_koolhyrdaten" required value='0'><span>%</span>
</div>
<div class="form_groep">
  <label class="input_label_eiwitten"><b>Eiwitten</b></label>
  <input class="input_macro_eiwitten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_eiwitten" required value='0'><span>%</span>
</div>
<div class="form_groep">
  <label class="input_label_vetten"><b>Vetten</b></label>
  <input class="input_macro_vetten" type="number" name="message" id="macro_vetten" required value='0'><span>%</span><br><br>
</div>
<div><span id="total">0</span> out of 100% </div>
```

Comment: Yes something went wrong with the java tag it wasn't suppose to be here. 

Yes! You understood me correctly and i want to give you a huge thank you!! I'm trying to implement your code into my javascript file right now. I will let you know when it works or when i cannot get it to work. Thanks again!

Comment: ok, nice to know. If it works, you can upvote and/or mark my answer as accepted. (I also made an adjustment in the code above)

Comment: I am running in the following problem, i haven't been clear enough. I want to add this code into my form but the form makes use of more inputs than just these 3. So i think when i use {const ipts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input'));} that it will select all the inputs within the form.

Comment: yes, it will select all `input`s of the document, if you want just some specif ones, then add a common class to the ones you want to select and use `document.getElementsByClassName('commonClass')`

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to `change` or `input` events from all of those inputs in js, and then get values from all, count their lengths and if `sum_of_their_lengths > some_maximum_value` then block them.